# Error: Getter not found: 'nonVirtual'. when compiling for device simulation

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart

I just updated to Xcode 11.6. I'm using Dart & Flutter to compile my code. Running the emulator for iPhone and Android works fine, but when I bring it over to Xcode to run on a device I get the error `Error: Getter not found: 'nonVirtual'.`

My guess is that it's a bug in either the latest release of Flutter or the latest release of Xcode.

```
Compiler message:
../../../../apps/flutter-projects/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/focus_traversal.dart:1125:4: Error: Getter not found: 'nonVirtual'.
  @nonVirtual
   ^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../apps/flutter-projects/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/focus_traversal.dart:1125:4: Error: This can't be used as metadata; metadata should be a reference to a compile-time constant variable, or a call to a constant constructor.
  @nonVirtual
   ^
../../../../apps/flutter-projects/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:507:4: Error: Getter not found: 'nonVirtual'.
  @nonVirtual
   ^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../apps/flutter-projects/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:507:4: Error: This can't be used as metadata; metadata should be a reference to a compile-time constant variable, or a call to a constant constructor.
  @nonVirtual
   ^
../../../../apps/flutter-projects/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:511:4: Error: Getter not found: 'nonVirtual'.
  @nonVirtual
   ^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../apps/flutter-projects/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:511:4: Error: This can't be used as metadata; metadata should be a reference to a compile-time constant variable, or a call to a constant constructor.
  @nonVirtual
   ^
../../../../apps/flutter-projects/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart:321:4: Error: Getter not found: 'nonVirtual'.
  @nonVirtual
   ^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../apps/flutter-projects/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart:321:4: Error: This can't be used as metadata; metadata should be a reference to a compile-time constant variable, or a call to a constant constructor.
  @nonVirtual
   ^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.


Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I only ran flutter upgrade then started getting the same message. (I'm developing using Android Studio).

The quickest workaround I found was by creating a new project and copying all the code I had written to the new project (leaving behind any autogenerated files).

This will most likely ruin my commit history but I needed to make an urgent presentation and its the only quick fix I could think of.

Answer (score -1):

Steps to reproduce

1. Run "flutter channel master".
2. Run "flutter upgrade".
3. Use charting library to draw pie chart.
4. Run "flutter run".

Workout already tried

1. flutter update-packages --force-upgrade
2. Invalidate cache and restart android studio
3. Deleted C:/Users/Paras/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache and rerun command "flutter run".